# Perl Warning: Use of uninitialized value while using string with multiple dots (.)

Tags: string, perl, string-interpolation

I'm Kinda new to Perl scripting. I am trying remote SSH to a Linux machine and my code as below:

```
my $hostname = "something.xyz.abc.com";
my $uid = "userid";
my $pwd = "pass";

my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($hostname);
$ssh->login($uid, $pwd);
my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd("ls -l");
print $stdout;
```

What is the reason I am seeing the

> "Use of uninitialized value while using string with multiple dots (.)"

warning? How to avoid/suppress it? Are those multiple dots creating issue?

The specific error message(s) are:

```
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at C:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib/Net/SSH/Perl/Key.pm line 13, <$fh> line 57.
Use of uninitialized value $blob in split at C:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib/Net/SSH/Perl/Key.pm line 41, <$fh> line 59.
Use of uninitialized value $ssh_name in hash element at C:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib/Net/SSH/Perl/Key.pm line 42, <$fh> line 59.
Use of uninitialized value in subroutine entry at C:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib/Net/SSH/Perl/Key.pm line 45, <$fh> line 59.
```

Comment: How is this `regex` related?

Comment: Can you telll the hostname that you are giving while executing??

Comment: Which line generates the error?

Comment: In fact, not any particular line in the code generating error. Here is part of the warning:

"Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at C:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib/Net/SSH/Perl/Key.pm line 13, <$fh> line 57."
"Use of uninitialized value $blob in split at C:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib/Net/SSH/Perl/Key.pm line 41, <$fh> line 59."
"Use of uninitialized value $ssh_name in hash element at C:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib/Net/SSH/Perl/Key.pm line 42, <$fh> line 59."
"Use of uninitialized value in subroutine entry at C:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib/Net/SSH/Perl/Key.pm line 45, <$fh> line 59."

Comment: line 13 of `NetLLSSH:Perl::Key` is doing 
        `$class .= "::" . shift();` As this is just a base clas, it expest a parameter to be passed to it of the type of key based exchange you will be using in you ssh connection so that it can then select the correct key implimentation. However since you are not passing any parameters along wity your hostname in your method call to ssh it doesnt know what type of key to use. Do you have default ssh path set up? it seems the value passed to Key class is empty so when it tries to concatenate it it throws a warning.

Comment: Are you using `-w` on the Perl command-line?  If so, don't: you can add `use warnings;` in your Perl files, but never use `-w` if you include other people's modules because it turns on warnings EVERYWHERE and modules often assume warnings are not enabled!